# 'User' object has no attribute 'staffUser'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, backend

I customized the User Model Using Django One To One Field

My models.py

```
class StaffUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

When uploading a form, i want to get the department of the user

'My Views.py'

```
   def FileUploadForm(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            u = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
            form.instance.username = u
            folder = Folder.objects.get(id=pk)
            department = u.staffUser.department
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'File Successfully uploaded to {folder} in {department}!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    context = {'pk':pk, 'form':form}
    return render(request, "pages/fileup_form.html", context)
```

But it gives error
AttributeError at /file/new/1
'User' object has no attribute 'staffUser'

Please guys i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `related_name` on your user field in `StaffUser` model

```
class StaffUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=staff_user)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Now you will be able to access StaffUser by `staff_user` on User object

Comment: I guess the related_name  staff_user is not part of the user object either way it would work  ....?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the reverse in lower case, so `staffuser` instead of `staffUser`.

Alternatively you can specify the related name to be used for calling the reverse accessor, as per below in place of `some_name`.

`user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=some_name)`